# Redpark RS232 is not returning desired data when writing/reading

Tags: ios, swift, serial-port, redpark

I've been stuck on this problem for several days now (I'm working remote for a company in the US and debugging on site is not possible).

The application I'm writing uses a Redpark RS232 serial cable which talks to a HAAS CNC machine [using Q Codes](https://diy.haascnc.com/data-collection-using-rs-232-port).  I wrote a Node.js app several months back that used a separate RS232 device (MOXA RS232 Wi-fi device) which worked almost perfectly but unfortunately Wi-Fi is not always stable on site so the Node server has been discontinued in favour of an iOS app that can persist machine state to the cloud as of when a network connection is available.

First and foremost the configuration of the HAAS machine is as follows (these settings used to work with the old RS232 device + server app):

[image: HAAS configuration for RS232 Port]

I then map this configuration in my app with:

```
func updateRS232Configuration() {
    if let _ = RS232Manager {
        settings.setNewValues(baudRate: 9600, dataBits: settings.DEFAULT_DATA_BITS, parity: settings.DEFAULT_PARITY, stopBits: settings.DEFAULT_STOP_BITS, rts: 1, cts: 1, DEBUG: true, ShowTxRx: true)

        RS232Manager?.setBaud(settings.baudRate!)     // 9600
        RS232Manager?.setDataSize(settings.dataBits!) // 7
        RS232Manager?.setParity(settings.parity!)     // Even
        RS232Manager?.setStopBits(settings.stopBits!) // 1

        var portConfig = serialPortConfig()
        RS232Manager?.getPortConfig(&portConfig)
        portConfig.rxFlowControl = settings.rts! // 0 (does this need to be enabled?)
        portConfig.txFlowControl = settings.cts! // 0
        portConfig.xonChar = 1
        portConfig.xoffChar = 1

        RS232Manager?.setPortConfig(&portConfig, requestStatus: false)

        self.performSelector(onMainThread: #selector(updateTextView), with: "Set the port configuration to: \(settings.toString())", waitUntilDone: false)
    }
}
```

This method gets called whenever the `cableConnected` callback is triggered (for now I'm hard coding the values but these will eventually be configurable).

When the cable connects and the serial port has been configured I sent a message to the serial cabe containing `Q100\r\n` I use the `\r\n` as stated in the HAAS configuration.  The only thing I'm worried about is that `writeString` (redparks write method) appends a null terminating byte, I thought it may be possible that the null terminate byte could cause the message to be misinterpreted on the HAAS so I set up two writes one after another:

```
func testWrite() {
        let str = commands.Q100
        let bytesToWrite = str.characters.count
        for index in 0...bytesToWrite-1 {
            let i = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: index)
            txBuffer[index] = Array(String(str[i]).utf8)[0]
        }

        RS232Manager?.write(&txBuffer, length: UInt32(bytesToWrite))

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.7, execute: {
            self.RS232Manager?.write("Q100\r\n")
        })
}
```

Normally I'd expect the HAAS to reply with something like (this is how the old app I wrote would display the response):

[image: old app response]

Instead I get a response like:

[image: Return message from HAAS]

When consulting the [HAAS Q Code documentation](https://diy.haascnc.com/data-collection-using-rs-232-port), this leads me to believe that I may be getting a response back from the machine and it just doesn't understand the message.

> If the control is busy, it outputs Status, Busy. If a request is not recognized, the control outputs **Unknown** and a new prompt **>**.

From the above screenshot we can see that a **>** is appended to the terminal but I'm not seeing an **Unknown** string, leading me to believe that it was not a malformed request.

I read the response back with:

```
func readBytesAvailable(_ length: UInt32) {
    if let bytesRead = RS232Manager?.read(&rxBuffer, length: length) {
        let byteStream : [UInt8] = Array(rxBuffer[0...Int(bytesRead)])
        if let resultString = String(bytes: byteStream, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii) {
            self.performSelector(onMainThread: #selector(updateTextView), with: "Got string: \(resultString)", waitUntilDone: false)
        } else {
            self.performSelector(onMainThread: #selector(updateTextView), with: "No string, got stream: \(byteStream)", waitUntilDone: false)
        }
    } else {
        self.performSelector(onMainThread: #selector(updateTextView), with: "No bytes available from host.", waitUntilDone: false)
    }
}
```

I have also tried using `getStringFromBytesAvailable` but that produces the same output, my read method above reads directly from the `rxBuffer`.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what I could be doing wrong?  Is my serial port configuration non-matching toward the one in the first image or am I writing my string incorrectly/reading incorrectly.  I've been stuck on this for days and feel like I'm getting nowhere.

Comment: Why did you set the xon and xoff char both to 1? Most serial devices use 0x11 for xon and 0x13 for xoff.

Comment: Hey thanks for the heads up! I didn't know what to set it too and just guessed they should both be 1 based on them both being present on the haas config panel

Comment: So set xon = 0x11 and xoff = 0x13 and lets see what would happen.

Comment: Worked a treat it seems that once the communication starts then the cable automatically resets the xon xoff state but the initial load wasn't working due to me setting it to 1, thanks a lot

Comment: Do you have the Swift source that implements the RedPark SDK on Github by any chance?

Comment: Hey I meant to close this question, I actually got it working, are you stuck too?

Comment: I've used the cable a few times with Objective-C, but I'm new to Swift, so any help would be awesome.

Comment: do you have skype or anything? I can't share the source code directly as my boss requested I close source the project, I'd  be more than happy to instruct you on getting started though :)

Comment: Ok, thank you for the offer. I'm in meetings most of today unfortunately. Is there a way to contact thru the profiles on this site?

Comment: I don't believe there is, I'll be around this evening - my Skype is alexsims1992

Comment: Ok, thank you in advance

Comment: Alex, is there a chance I could get the Swift source as well?  I am using this for iPad and Arduino communication.

Comment: I'll be on Skype all day tomorrow if you want to add me. I'll be happy to talk over how to implement it with swift (alexsims1992)